# How to call a function inside an object

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript about a week ago and I have run in to a bit of a stumbling block. In the link provided, I for whatever reason cannot call the function inside the object. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any advice would be great.

[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJvf.png)

Comment: Try just using `this` instead of `this.word` and you'll see that the console gives you different values for `this` based on where you are.

Comment: That syntax looks off to me.  When defining the function as part of the object, you already gave it a name... `bar`.  I don't think `test` should be there too.  Something like: `bar: function() { ... }`

Comment: @David, the syntax is odd, I agree, but it works: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv6bf76n/).

Comment: @lzzlbk, let me suggest you to consider using a web site like https://jsfiddle.net next question

Comment: @MassimilianoCarosi: Interesting.  I wonder if it works intentionally by spec or works coincidentally as undefined behavior.  The latter may be browser-specific.  Either way, I'd still recommend never doing that as it makes the intent unclear.  Good test, though.

Comment: Just so you know, on SO it is [preferred that you include the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you are having problems with in your question instead of just linking to something. That way anyone finding your question can still benefit from it even if the link is broken.

Comment: @UselessCode Thank you for the heads up, will definitely take that into consideration next time around.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function, but the function is returning undefined. Be aware of the fact that `this` has different meanings called in different context, in `testObj`, `this == testObj`, hence `this.word` is undefined.

Maybe this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmLrzmyd/1/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testObj = {
   bar: function(){
console.log(this.word)
}
}
```

When you call testObj.bar
Here this refers to the testObj and testObj has no property word

```
var testObj = {
   bar: function(){
console.log(this.word)
}.bind(this)
}
```

Use .bind(this) or .bind(window)

Answer (score 0):

Because the scope has changed.

> In JavaScript, scope refers to the current context of your code. Scopes can be globally or locally defined. Understanding JavaScript scope is key to writing bulletproof code and being a better developer. You’ll understand where variables/functions are accessible, be able to change the scope of your code’s context and be able to write faster and more maintainable code, as well as debug much faster.

So the correct code is:

```
var that = this;
var testObject = { bar: function() { return that.word }}
```

In your solution, "this" is "window" object. So you also can code this:

```
var testObject = { bar: function() { return window.word }}
```